# How do I write the following time stamp into a text file every minute?

Tags: python, time, process, background

I am trying to make the below code write to a file 
every minute and run in the background all day. 
I want this program to start on computer startup. Any 
help would be much appreciated as I am a Novice!
I will access the data in this text file randomly throughout the day.

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

def timechange():
    with open('timestamp', 'w') as f:
        d_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        reg_format_date = d_date.strftime("%I:%M %p CT %m/%d/%Y")
        f.write('%s BRIAN BISSLAND \nCONFIRMED MATERIAL, QUANTITY, PRICING AND CDD' % reg_format_date)
        sleep(1)

for i in range(10):
    timechange()
```

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: On Windows you can add a start-up task that runs your script, or alternatively add a Shortcut that does so to your `Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` folder. The actually folder path will vary depending on which version you're running.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this script on Linux server, you can use Crontab to call this script regularly. Windows server you may use scheduled task.